# JIT building a functional json for organisation chart

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to build a json request required for JIT SpaceTree.

**The workflow**: a question is started with the id of the retrospective answer stored.

- If the option is yes then it loads the next question based on the load_yes value. this load_yes value selects the id and loads that question.
- If the option is no it loads the next no based question by its id stored under load_no,

json should look like:

```
var json = {
        id: "start",
        name: "does test work?",
        data: {},
        children: [{
            id: "layer1_1",
            name: "option: no, id 3, Q: test does work with option no?",
            data: {},
            children: []
        }, {
            id: "layer1_2",
            name: "option: yes, id 2, Q:  test does work!!",
            data: {},
            children: [{
                id: "layer2_1",
                name: "option: no, id 4, Q: test does work?",
                data: {},
                children: []
            }, {
                id: "layer2_2",
                name: "option: yes, id 5, Q: ",
                data: {},
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    };
```

---

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM topic_answer");

while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){
    $arr[] = array(
        'id' => $obj->id,
        'name' => $obj->topic_question,
        'data' => '',
        'children' => array(array(
            'id' => $obj->load_yes,
            'name' => $obj->load_yes,
            'data' => '',
            'children' =>array(),
            ),array(
                'id' => $obj->load_no,
                'name' => $obj->load_no,
                'data' => '',
                'children' => array(),

            ),
        )
    );
```

---

```
     id, topic_name,  topic_creator, topic_question,  load_yes,  start,  load_no,   end 
     1    test        jordan       does test work?         2          1       3          0
     4    test        jordan       test does work no       0          0       0          0
     5    test        jordan       test does work yes      0          0       0          0
     2    test        jordan       test does work yes!!    4          0       5          0
```

Comment: so, any luck with that?

Comment: just updated the script 5minutes ago, couple of teething issues, but your way of doing it seems to work :) thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

in json, objects are depicted as `{}`. so basically what this code means is an array of objects:

```
[
  {},
  {}
]
```

so here, where you are nesting arrays:

```
'children' => array(array(
    'id' => $obj->load_yes,
    'name' => $obj->load_yes,
    'data' => '',
    'children' =>array(),
    ),array(
        'id' => $obj->load_no,
        'name' => $obj->load_no,
        'data' => '',
        'children' => array(),
    ),
)
```

you actually want to replace the inner array by an *object*, such as stdClass(). stdClass is used like this:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->id = "layer1_1";
$obj->name = "option: no, id 3, Q: test does work with option no?";
$obj->data = new stdClass();
$obj->children = array();
```

then, with php

```
'children' => array(
    $obj1,
    $obj2,
),
```